# How to implement added cost point barrier in ArcMap Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, origin-destination

I am trying to figure out how the cost point barrier in Network Analyst works. I am doing an OD cost matrix and I want to add border crossing points as cost point barrier. Is it possible to configure the values of cost point barrier with border delays in minutes so that it will add to the total travel distance once the OD cost matrix is solved? I found some references like the ff. but nothing mentioned about how to implement it.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/barriers.htm 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/creating-network-analysis-objects-with-the-create-network-locations-tool.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. You have to right click on the network analysis object and you can input the values in minutes as shown here on the screenshot
[image]